# In which section of a program does (const char const * pointer = "Hello") resides?

Tags: c, memory-management, x86

Let us say we have a (char *pointer = "hello") in my program. I know that the pointer will be in the data section, and "hello" will be in rodata section.
My question is, what if the pointer and the characters are both constants, are they both going to be stored in rodata section?

Comment: It is dependent on the compiler/target environment etc. Assuming GCC with ELF  - if you declare `const char const * pointer = "Hello")` at global scope (and non-static) the pointer should be in an .rodata.* section as well as the string it points at.

Comment: What if they were static?

Comment: Looking at that statement again, maybe you mean `const char* const pointer = "Hello"` . I misread what you had originally.

Comment: `const char const * pointer = "Hello";` is basically putting `const` twice on the data. I think you intended to make it a constant pointer to constant data, in which case the second `const` should have been after `*` and not before it so should have been `const char* const pointer = "Hello";`` instead

Comment: Exactly, I was asking about the case where both the pointer and the data are constants.

Comment: Is the line `char *pointer = "hello";` written inside a function or at file scope?  The answer for where `pointer` is stored depends on the location (as well as the compiler and o/s you're using, etc; it isn't defined in the C standard).  Adding `static` is another factor — it only changes things when the definition is at function scope.  And changing the explicit const-ness has some effect at file scope or with `static` but not for a definition with function scope.

Comment: I tried to tell you that `const char const * pointer = "Hello"`  is not a const pointer to const data. That is the same as writing `const const char * pointer = "Hello"` . `const const char` is the same as `const char`. If you want a constant pointer to constant data then it would have to be `const char * const pointer = "Hello"`. The second `const` has to be placed after the `*`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Would you mind to put your insights into an answer, please?